# Screen flicker present in all operating systems after error in Ubuntu Touch [Nexus 7 2012 wifi]

Tags: android, screen, flicker

I installed Ubuntu Touch stable 10 with MultiRom. When I swiped from left to right Ubuntu froze and the screen started to flicker.

I have removed Ubuntu Touch and still have the stock Android 4.4.4 Rom and Cyanogen 10.2 custom Rom. The screen flickers in both of these Roms now. Most notably when I swipe down the notifications tray and the home screen darkens (or any other time parts of the screen darken).

Did Ubuntu Touch damage my devices hardware when it crashed? Is there some kind of cache that needs to be cleared to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a hardware problem for sure, unfourtunately.
There is just no way the Ubuntu install could have caused that.
When another OS is running, Ubuntu can not influence anything, even if it would be still installed.

Comment: Any idea if I can diagnose it somehow? Is there an app for that? It would at least be nice to know what's broken.

I know they said "install at your own risk" but DAMNIT!

Comment: I do not think it is related to the install at all, just coincidence.

Comment: Apparently when the flicker error appears the device is put under a lot of stress. It definitely failed then.

The good news is, it's not so bad. The flicker is only visible in the MultiRom boot menu and when the screen darkens (when you pull the tray down, or when you get a popup.

I guess I can live with that :)

Comment: You mean the brightness on the whole screen area is flickering> That could be a weak connection to the backlight power.

Comment: It looks exactly like a bad connection to the backlight power, but is only triggered in a few circumstances, particularly when parts of the screen darken (when you pull the notification tray down or a popup comes up, the area around them will darken, and in that darkness I notice the flicker).

It's very little noticeable now. That's why I suspected that it may not be a hardware problem, but rather some kind of cache problem.

Even in Ubuntu when it first happened, the whole screen didn't flicker, just the darkened area "below" the app tray.